# Rails, Cucumber: external redirection to another domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, external, redirect, capybara

I have cucumber feature

```
...
Given I am on my domain page
When I press "send data to external domain"
Then I should be on the externel domain page
...
```

In production and development enviroments "My domain page" (www.example.com/mydomainpage) redirects user to "external domain page" (www.externaldomain.com/page). But in test enviroment cucumber cut off domain part of url:

```
Redirected to http://www.externaldomain.com/page
Completed 302 Found in 17895ms


Started GET "/page" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-10-11 19:06:48 +0400
  SQL (72.0ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Is it possible to set up cucumber to redirect to various domain, not only current server domain?

P.S. Cucumber + Capybara + Rails + Rspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do such thing (Selenium, Culerity and etc...). Best way is using [capybara-mechanize](https://github.com/jeroenvandijk/capybara-mechanize), the RackTest driver for Capybara with remote request support. This is very cool tool!

Comment: Didn't work for me, aparently I can set Capybara.app_host = "http://www.yourapp.com" to some remote app and get it tested but running locally doesn't treats external redirects as relative.